# JavaFX Observables: signal from ObservableArrayList to ObservableList

Tags: javafx, observablelist

I have a TableView (javafx.scene.control.TableView) which I populated with data.
This data is retreived from the database as an ArrayList, so I used the folowing flow:

```
private ObservableList<Budget> budgetsObservable;
private ArrayList<Budget> budgetsArray;
```

I populate the ArrayList with budget data

```
budgetsArray= wrapper.findAllBudget();
```

I initialize the ObservableList with the data array

```
budgetsObservable = FXCollections.observableArrayList(budgetsArray);
```

To my TableView (TableView, I add my ObservableList

```
tableViewBudget.setItems(budgetsObservable);
```

I update the values in the array

```
budgetsArray = wrapper.UpdateBudget();
```

The initial data is shown correctly.
I was expecting that by changing the ArrayList(last step), the ObservableList would see the change and pass it to my TableView. What would be the flow in order to make the change in the array result in the TableView being signalled and updated with the new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
budgetsObservable.setAll(wrapper.updateBudget());
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! In case you want to update a Table like in my case, it was necessary to first call a .clear() on the ObservableList, or else the data will be appended to the allready listed data.

Comment: setAll will work. You must have used addAll by mistake.